# FOS User Bundle Form Override

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I am using FOS User Bundle + Symfony2.3.
I want to override FOS User Bundle Form. Override and want to add login and registration Form in header file . For show in header I am using javascript.For example when I click tab-2 then open Registration form

One thing simply I am override this and this is working but When Registration Form call in other html then It is not working

I was doing this but this is So me error :

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form.
```

I do not know Why ?

My file is :

HeaderController.php

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\FrontBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use XYZ\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType;

class HeaderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/header", name="header")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $registrationForm = $this->createForm(new RegistrationFormType());
        return array('registration_form'   => $registrationForm->createView());
    }
}
?>
```

Header(index.html.twig):-

```
{# Signup #}
<div id="tab-2" class="login_form">
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(registration_form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
<label><strong>Full Name</strong>
{{ form_widget(registration_form.username) }}
</label>
<label><strong>Email Address</strong>
{{ form_widget(registration_form.email) }}
</label>
<label><strong>Password</strong>
{{form_errors(registration_form.plainPassword)}}
{{ form_widget(registration_form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr':{'label': 'Password:'}  }) }}
</label>
<label><strong>Confirm Password</strong>
{{form_errors(registration_form.plainPassword)}}
{{ form_widget(registration_form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr':{ 'label': 'Retype Password:'} }) }}</label>
<input type="submit" class="submitBut" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}"/>
</form>
</div>
```

RegistrationFormType.php

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class RegistrationFormType extends AbstractType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
    $builder
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => 'form.username', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => 'form.password'),
            'second_options' => array('label' => 'form.password_confirmation'),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
    ;
   }

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
   {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => "XYZ\UserBundle\Entity\User"
    ));
   }


   public function getName()
   {
    return 'xyz_user_registration';
   }
}
```

Services.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

<services>
    <service id="xyz_user.registration.form.type" class="XYZ\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType">
        <tag name="form.type" alias="xyz_user_registration" />
        <argument>%fos_user.model.user.class%</argument>
    </service>
</services>
</container>
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\UserBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccountStatusException;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;

/**
 * Controller managing the registration
 *
 */
class RegistrationController extends ContainerAware
{
  public function registerAction()
  {
    $form = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form');
    $formHandler = $this->container->get('fos_user.registration.form.handler');
    $confirmationEnabled = $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.registration.confirmation.enabled');

    $process = $formHandler->process($confirmationEnabled);
    if ($process) {
        $user = $form->getData();

        $authUser = false;
        if ($confirmationEnabled) {
            $this->container->get('session')->set('fos_user_send_confirmation_email/email', $user->getEmail());
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_check_email';
        } else {
            $authUser = true;
            $route = 'fos_user_registration_confirmed';
        }

        $this->setFlash('fos_user_success', 'registration.flash.user_created');
        $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($route);
        $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

        if ($authUser) {
            $this->authenticateUser($user, $response);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('XYZUserBundle:Registration:register.html.'.$this->getEngine(), array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
   }
}
?>
```

config.yml

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: XYZ\UserBundle\Entity\User

    registration:
        form:
            type: xyz_user_registration
            name: xyz_user_registration_form
            validation_groups:  [Registration, Default]
```

Thanks!

Comment: try with
`use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;
    
    class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType`

Comment: in your twig `{{ form_rest(registration_form) }}`

Comment: I used this with every field but this is not working then I was remove this.

Comment: no for every Field. Try to do `{{ form_end(form) }}` or `{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}`. See http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/reference/forms/twig_reference.html#form-end-view-variables

Comment: Can you post the answer with my twig file if possible boz may I am doing something wrong in twig.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44104/discussion-between-kunwar-siddharth-singh-and-barno)

Answer (score 6):

The form submission use an a CRSF token contained in an hidden input. you don't insert this input in your view.
Try to insert this line before your submit button :

```
{{ form_rest(registration_form) }}
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem I had, but pointed me in the right way. Thx

Answer (score 2):

Your FormType is not Correct. Check https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseType;

class RegistrationFormType extends BaseType
{
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
       parent::buildForm($builder, $options);      
   }

   public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
   {
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => "XYZ\UserBundle\Entity\User"
    ));
   }


   public function getName()
   {
    return 'xyz_user_registration';
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok but when I used this then show me error in HeaderController.php Where I create form object.  
ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct(), called in /var/www/xyz.com/abc/src/XYZ/FrontBundle/Controller/BlockHeaderController.php on line 18 and defined in /var/www/xyz.com/abc/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Typ‌​e/RegistrationFormType.php line 25

Comment: because you don't `extends BaseType` but `extends AbstractType`. 
Check `/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Type/RegistrationFormType.php` this is a `BaseType` that `extends AbstractType`

Comment: you have to Follow [FosUserBundle Doc](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle)

Comment: I am edit my form and paste your code then show me this error.

Comment: This is right way to create object in controller :   $registrationForm = $this->createForm(new RegistrationFormType());
  return array('registration_form'   => $registrationForm->createView());

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44109/discussion-between-kunwar-siddharth-singh-and-barno)

Comment: I follow the fos doc and as it Wright RegistrationFormType.php as you told but show me error : ContextErrorException: Warning: Missing argument 1 for FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType::__construct(), called in /var/www/xyz.com/abc/src/XYZ/FrontBundle/Controller/BlockHeaderController.php on line 18 and defined in /var/www/xyz.com/abc/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Form/Typ‌​‌​e/RegistrationFormType.php line 25

Answer (score 0):

`{{ form_end(form) }}` worked for me. It **adds all the missing fields**, that you might forgot to add. The hidden **token-input-field*** for example.

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
    {{form_label(form.email)}}: {{form_widget(form.email)}}
    {# ... #}
    {{ form_end(form) }}
</form>
```

*

```
<input type="hidden" id="fos_user_registration_form__token" name="fos_user_registration_form[_token]" value="fsdfsdfsdf" />
```

Hope it helps someone. :-)